# Keeping Hash Value Hidden

Tags: java, android, security, hash, cryptography

I am developing an Android application that communicates with a REST API that I developed. The REST API is hosted on a separate server and the application will poke at the endpoints to send & receive information.

For authorization purposes, whenever an endpoint is touched by the application, the request must also contain the user's key and hash. The key is a public number received from a 3rd party service and the hash is what I need to actually implement.

Because Android can easily be decompiled and read, I need a way to actually generate the hash yet hide it from prying eyes. I know that obfuscating the code won't hide strings so I can't put any secret key within the application. I have also considered having the hash generated through the REST API, but that would still allow someone else to access it.

I'm kind of running out of ideas and this is one of the most important parts of the application for obvious security reasons. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Edit: I'm going to provide more information to help you understand how the application works. My application requires that the user logs in with Facebook so that (typically) legitimate information is provided. I use the ID of the user from Facebook as the public key and I planned on using a separate hash value to keep their account secret. The problem is that there is no unique value that I have from the user because the only information provided is through Facebook. I can't use hardware information as a unique value because they could always change their device in the future. For those of you that have used Tinder or seen how Tinder functions, they only require that you log in with Facebook. I aim to have that same functionality. I would prefer to not have to ask them for any information upon registering/logging in.

Comment: "The key is a public number received from a 3rd party service" -- that would seem to be the problem. You need your credentials for your API to be something that the *user* cares about defending, such as a user ID/password pair tied to a user account on the server. Then, it doesn't matter if the hashing algorithm is visible, because that algorithm is only useful if you already have a user ID/password pair.

Comment: How about reading the preferred hashalgorithm from file a config file or something like that

Comment: The 3rd party service is Facebook. The way my application functions is that the user MUST login with Facebook. The reason I do this is because it provides me (typically) legitimate information about the user. So the account of the user for the application is linked directly with Facebook. No password, username, etc. is needed.

Comment: @zaph I have provided more information in the question.

Comment: Note that you still have not explained why you think that you need to obscure the hash algorithm. If you want a plain hash algorithm, use SHA256 and a decent salt. Or, use bcrypt or scrypt. More to the point, nobody should be writing their own hash algorithms, so hopefully you're going to be using something tested by somebody other than yourself, and you can't obscure somebody else's implementation very well.

Comment: I agree with @CommonsWare, you can decompile an established hash algorithm such as SHA256 all you want, it'll still be secure. If you can enforce the secrecy and integrity of the actual _input_ to the hash (like a challenge sent from the server) through TLS, you are half-way there. The other half is the real issue. If there isn't _any_ unique, private value associated with the user, how is this scheme supposed to verify anything or be resistant to spoofing? I would recommend going back to the drawing board, create a threat model for your application and work your way forward.

Answer (score 0):

So after hours of thinking and re-planning the authentication and security system, I decided to use the Facebook SDK to receive unique values for each user that is logged in. I don't know why I didn't think of it before, it was sitting in front of me the whole time, but I decided to use Facebook's access token system as the means of authentication.

When a user logs into Facebook for the first time, an access token is generated by Facebook that is 72 characters long, I believe. I send this access token along with the user ID to my Rest API which sends a request to Facebook with the user access token. This request checks to see if the access token is valid and if it is it returns the user ID it is associated with. I use that ID to match with the user ID given in the original request to my API and if they match it authorizes the user and allows them to use the API.

Answer (score -2):

You can try generating the hash via your API, then store it locally using Android's [Keystore API](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html). That should provide fairly reasonable security - though if someone is hell-bent on getting a specific hash, they probably will. But at least they won't have the actual algorithm.

Comment: Security is not achived by keeping an algorithm secret.

Comment: I'm going to assume that every person is "hell-bent on getting a specific hash". Security is something of top importance so I don't want to knowingly release an application with the possibility of it being hacked.

Comment: @Jmrapp in that case, you're out of luck. No amount of black magic is going to prevent someone from eventually figuring out your hash.

Comment: @Melllvar I'd prefer to prevent them from figuring it out as long as possible. Generating the hash via my API would mean that it would have to be public to the internet. It would take a person under an hour to decompile my application and find the endpoint that gives them that hash value.

Comment: While @Melllvar is correct what is needed is to determine the level of security need considering the cost. The point is to increase the work factor above the point of required security. Amoung other things is it much harder to protect something from the device owner/user than someone else. Does the atttacker have the device or is the attack on or from the Internet?

Comment: @zaph Yes I agree. I understand that anything is 'hackable', but I'd like to make that process as tough as possible.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Keystore API is the core of my answer here. Downvoting is fine and all, but I doubt you'll find a more secure way to store data on an Android device without it.

Comment: @Melllvar The suggestion you provided makes the way your storing the hash irrelevant. You suggest for the application to get the hash via my REST API. This API is completely public so any person can use it's functions if they have the right key. The key is public so if they find the public key, which is simple, they can request the hash through their web browser. Hence the way it is stored on Android is useless.

Comment: @zaph Clearly I'm not arguing with that. However, OP needs to come up with a minimum risk, and I doubt even he knows what it is. Complete security is impossible.

Comment: @Jmrapp That depends on how you generate your hash, and I don't think your question contains enough information to completely address it. Generate a random hash, store it on the server, and send it to the client (to store securely). It doesn't matter who calls that API - since each hash is unique, users can't really spoof each other.

Comment: I know that using my own user account system would completely get rid of this issue, but my intentions are for the user to only have to log in via Facebook. How do you think Tinder provides this functionality without risking security? There must be some unique value they use along with the Facebook information. The only question is what is this unique value and how is it generated and hidden from prying eyes.

Comment: @Mellvar That's not completely true. Lets say for example that the user logs in for the first time, the random value is generated on the server, and it is stored on the android side as well. That works fine. Now whenever the user uses the application, they have the private key on their device. But say that the user switches to a new device. That user doesn't have the hash on their device. We could send them the hash and have them save it, but that means that any person who, through my API, requests the hash with the public ID from Facebook can get the hash of that corresponding user.

Comment: @Jmrapp in that case, the scope of your question is woefully inadequate. You're basically asking for a complete authentication solution within the confines of a SO question.

Comment: @Melllvar Not at all. I am asking for suggestions as to how to how to get a unique value that could be used as a hashing value. The only constraint is that I only want to use the Facebook API for user authentication.